# Implementing facebook-like chat in app engine standard java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, chat

I've been studying App Engine for a work assignment which is to implement a chat service similar to Facebook's desktop page chatting. I had previously implemented something similar but since it ran on proprietary servers where there was no limit to traffic and technologies, I'm not sure that same implementation will work on App Engine.

Some things to notice:

- This is for a web page/app. There is no specific messaging client application
- App Engine doesn't support websockets
- App Engine doesn't allow threads to outlive their requests (meaning I can't hold a background thread that awaits for new messages and pushes them to the user)
- App Engine wants to service requests in a matter of seconds. I had thought of using long polling like facebook does but I'm not sure if this will be allowed
- Is long polling every 30 seconds even an option? I'm afraid it massively increases my traffic costs...
- I looked at XMPP but I think it doesn't really apply to web applications. Also I think I read somewhere in the docs that it is not/will not be supported anymore?

I'd like some advice on how I should go about this. I'm going to use `Cloud Datastore` for storage and I was hoping to implement this as a simple RESTful microservice to be honest but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: Have you already looked into its [Channel API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/channel/?csw=1)?

Comment: Oops, it looks like they are [deprecating](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/channel) it. There is a suggested [alternative](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine) though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge **goole app engine** with **google firebase** to easily achieve a realtime chat application

you can access the realtime database on firebase using only javascript to update and display chats

Comment: This seems like a really good option actually. And I see it has a free package which is really important for our prototyping stage. I'll try to create a prototype today and see if it actually helps